# How to use find + regex to match files and return only unique directories containing said files?

Tags: regex, linux, find

This find command matches the files I'm searching for:

```
find / -type f -regextype sed -regex ".*/g\.[0-9]\{4\}.*"
```

How do I move to the next step of listing just the unique directory names that contain those files? (I don't need to display all the files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output to a `sed` command that removes the filenames, and then use `uniq` to remove duplicates:

```
find / -type f -regextype sed -regex ".*/g\.[0-9]\{4\}.*" | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | uniq
```